# Untar and gzip compress from multiple sub directories

Tags: linux, gzip, tar

I have a directory which consists of multiple sub-directories. Each subdirectory has a tar.gz file which on untar gives two files namely dirname_R1.fastq and dirname_R2.fastq. I want to untar the tar file and compress dirname_R1.fastq and dirname_R2.fastq immediately after piping,and save the output(dirname_R1.fastq.gz,dirname_R2.fastq.gz) of each sub-directories into another SINGLE directory.

```
sourcedir=/sdir
destdir=/ddir

for f in $sourcedir/*; do
  fbase=${f##*/}   
  echo "Inside $fbase"
  tar -xvf $f/*.gz |gzip -n9 $f/*.fastq > $destdir/
done
```

I wrote the above code but it goes until the echo command.